# Auto refresh of page in Rails 3 using javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a view in my rails app: blah.app/units/status

This displays a status of all my units.  I'd like to have the page automatically refresh via javascript but I'm not sure how to do it.

I tried writing this but it doesn't reload:

```
<script>
  $(function() {
    setInterval(function(){
      $.getScript("/units/status");
    }, 10000);
  });
</script>
```

Can someone point out where I'm going wrong here?

Comment: I also tried this which works, but not sure if it's the best way to do it.  '<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">setTimeout("location.reload();",10000);</script>'

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    window.location.reload();
  }, 10000);
});
```

Comment: jQuery isn't tagged, and there's no reason to wait until the DOM is ready anyways

Comment: I don't see your witty solution to teknull problem, just complaining about the given solutions... that work.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. For some reason, I was focusing on teknull's comment to his question, that already tried basically what you have. So I don't know how I missed that they are already using jQuery - that's my fault. But I don't see where I was complaining though. It would probably help if you explained some or proved that your almighty code worked, instead of just posting code.